# How can I add transform to unicode letters

Tags: javascript, css, dom, unicode, css-animations

I am working on some text animation on my language. But separating the letters to spans using a js, results in something like follows:

```
<span class="letter" style="transform: translate(0.55em, 1.1em) scale(1.5);">ध</span>
<span class="letter" style="transform: translate(0.55em, 1.1em);">्</span>
<span class="letter" style="transform: translate(0.55em, 1.1em);">य</span>
<span class="letter" style="transform: translate(0.55em, 1.1em);">ो</span>
```

The Script I use is

```
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");
```

and results in html is as follows

[image]

The result should look like:  **ध्यो** because those empty spaces get combined in unicode.

It only breaks when `.letter` is applied with `display:inline-block` which is required to apply transforms.

Is there a way I can achieve result of **ध्यो** and still apply transforms to each letter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that language you must separate them by words as separating by letters won't work. The following code should work.

```js
        let textEl = document.querySelector("p");
        if (textEl) {
            let words = textEl.textContent.split(" ");
            let finalStr = words.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex) => {
                return currentIndex === 1 ?
                    `<span class='word'>${accumulator}</span> <span class='word'>${currentValue}</span>` :
                    `${accumulator} <span class='word'>${currentValue}</span>`
                    ;
            });
            textEl.innerHTML = finalStr;
        }
        console.log(textEl.innerHTML);
```

```html
<p>some text for testing</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the whitespace -

Update: I see, you cannot do inline-block then

Translate works only on

> block-level or atomic inline-level element, or whose ‘display’ property computes to ‘table-row’, ‘table-row-group’, ‘table-header-group’, ‘table-footer-group’, ‘table-cell’, or ‘table-caption’ [CSS21]

```js
document.getElementById("letterDiv").innerText = document.getElementById("spanDiv").innerText;
```

```css
.letter {
  transform: translate(0.55em, 1.1em) scale(1.5);
  color: green;
}

div.letter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
With whitespace<br/>
<span class="letter">ध</span>
<span class="letter">्</span>
<span class="letter">य</span>
<span class="letter">ो</span>
<hr/> Without

<br/>
<div id="spanDiv">
  <span class="letter">ध</span><span class="letter">्</span><span class="letter">य</span><span class="letter">ो</span>
</div>
<br/>
<hr/> Block
:<br/>

<div class="letter" id="letterDiv"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think I have whitespaces in my solution. That's just what I pasted from dev tools. My code actually looks like `textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");
` so it breaks string into spans and that's what I get. I don't think this code includes whitespaces

Comment: So what if you do NOT break it into spans but insert it into an innerHTML in one chunk like I did in my div?

Comment: I need to break them because I am applying animations to different letters. I am looking for result similar to this `https://tobiasahlin.com/moving-letters/#7`

Comment: I would say that is not possible using your alphabet

Comment: Yeah I got to the same conclusion myself. I decided to go word by word in the end. Thanks anyway :)